# ¿Como cambiar tamaño del terminal linux al ejecutar un script python?

Tags: python, linux, consola

Estoy escribiendo un script python y deseo ejecutar con un cierto tamaño de consola. Ej: 42x10

Comment: ¿Has intentado/investigado algo?

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, veo que su experiencia lo avala :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende de la consola. Para cmd por ejemplo usarias:

```
import os
os.system('mode con: cols=10 lines=42')
```

Por otro lado, para xterm podrías usar:

```
import os
os.system('printf "\033[8;10;42t"')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo. exito...